# EF Core join entity IQueryable with id IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I try to join a `IQueryable<int>`, which is a list of entity ids with an `IQueryable<Entity>`.

For this I use the following code:

```
IQueryable<Entity> entityQuery = _context.Entities.Where(x => ...);
IQueryable<int> idQuery = _context.AccessRights.Where(x => ...).Select(x => x.Id);
query = entityQuery.Join(idQuery, x => x.Id, x => x, (x, y) => x);
```

This code is working with in-memory lists, however if I try it with LINQ to sql, the `Join` is getting ignored.

I don't want to load the ids into memory. Is this even possible with LINQ to SQL?

Comment: `_context.Ids` is mapped to database table? No, that's not possible, what actually is this `IQueryable<int>`?

Comment: @IvanStoev `IQueryable<int>` is a selection of multiple entity ids, which have a matching Entity.Id.

Comment: EF Core has a concept of splitting the query which cannot translate to SQL to several parts, execute them separately and merge them in memory. If you turn the logging on, you'll see at least 2 SQL queries executed, and yes, `entityQuery` will not have a `join`, but the result should be accounting it.

Comment: *This code is working with in-memory lists* Then what are `_context.AccessRights` and `_context.Entities`?

Comment: @GertArnold Hi, it's just another current EF Core failure (I've told you - it's not ready to be used yet). I've tried something similar and it really does 2 db queries and in-memory join :(

Comment: Sure. Sigh... The beta was an alpha, the release is a beta. It seems to me that the whole world is in a hurry nowadays.

Comment: @GertArnold Indeed - especially open source :) Right after commenting here, I had to comment/answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351213/entity-framework-one-to-many-relationship/40351462?noredirect=1#comment67958146_40351462), etc. etc. Crazy :)

Comment: @GertArnold `_context.AccessRights` and `_context.Entities` are both DbSets.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
IQueryable<Entity> entityQuery = _context.Entities.Where(x => ...);
IQueryable<int> idQuery = _context.AccessRights.Where(x => ...).Select(x => x.Id);
entityQuery = entityQuery.Where(x => idQuery.Contains(x.Id));
```

This will get the result you're looking for without loading the ids into memory. But it may convert it into a giant SQL IN statement, which wouldn't be ideal.

Or you can join to AccessRights directly:

```
IQueryable<Entity> entityQuery = from e in _context.Entities.Where(x => ...)
                                 join ar in _context.AccessRights.Where(x => ...)
                                     on e.Id equals ar.Id
                                 select e;
```