# Entity Framework One to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My EF query takes around 3 seconds to fetch 10 players because it fetches all 500k+ rows of the other table, instead of the few I need.

This is the PlayerEntity:

```
namespace RocketLeagueStats.Database.Entities
{
    [Table("players", Schema = "public")]
    public class PlayerEntity
    {

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("unique_id")]
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }

        [Column("display_name")]
        public string DiplayName { get; set; }

        [Column("platform_id")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PlatformId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PlatformId")]
        public PlatformEntity Platform { get; set; }

        [Column("avatar")]
        public string Avatar { get; set; }

        public PlayerStatsEntity Stats { get; set; }

        public List<PlayerRankedEntity> Ranks { get; set; }

        [Column("last_requested")]
        public DateTime LastRequested { get; set; }

        [Column("created_at")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column("updated_at")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the PlayerRankedEntity:

```
namespace RocketLeagueStats.Database.Entities
{
    [Table("player_ranked", Schema = "public")]
    public class PlayerRankedEntity
    {

        [ForeignKey("Player")]
        [Column("player_id")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }

        [Column("season_id")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int SeasonId { get; set; }

        [Column("playlist_id")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

        [Column("matches_played")]
        public int MatchesPlayed { get; set; }

        [Column("rank_points")]
        public int RankPoints { get; set; }

        [Column("tier")]
        public int Tier { get; set; }

        [Column("division")]
        public int Division { get; set; }

        public PlayerEntity Player { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the PlayerStatsEntity:

```
namespace RocketLeagueStats.Database.Entities
{
    [Table("player_stats", Schema = "public")]
    public class PlayerStatsEntity
    {

        [Key, ForeignKey("Player")]
        [Column("player_id")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }

        [Column("wins")]
        public int Wins { get; set; }

        [Column("goals")]
        public int Goals { get; set; }

        [Column("mvps")]
        public int Mvps { get; set; }

        [Column("saves")]
        public int Saves { get; set; }

        [Column("shots")]
        public int Shots { get; set; }

        [Column("assists")]
        public int Assists { get; set; }

        public PlayerEntity Player { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my DatabaseContext.OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerRankedEntity>()
        .HasKey(k => new { k.PlayerId, k.SeasonId, k.PlaylistId });
}
```

This is the code that takes over 3 seconds to complete (If I remove '.Include(x => x.Ranks)' it just takes a few ms):

```
using (var database = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var serviceProvider = database.GetInfrastructure();
    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var players = database.Players
        .Include(x => x.Ranks)
        .Take(10)
        .ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine($"Took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms to fetch {players.Length} players");
}
```

This is the output, notice that it generates two queries instead of one:

```
2016-10-31 22:50:18.6416 INFO Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "x"."id", "x"."avatar", "x"."created_at", "x"."display_name", "x"."last_requested", "x"."platform_id", "x"."unique_id", "x"."updated_at"
FROM "public"."players" AS "x"
ORDER BY "x"."id"
LIMIT @__p_0
2016-10-31 22:50:18.7128 INFO Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "p"."player_id", "p"."season_id", "p"."playlist_id", "p"."division", "p"."matches_played", "p"."rank_points", "p"."tier"
FROM "public"."player_ranked" AS "p"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "public"."players" AS "x"
    WHERE "p"."player_id" = "x"."id"
    LIMIT @__p_0)
ORDER BY "p"."player_id"
Took 3991ms to fetch 10 players
```

I think that I messed up on the relations somewhere, causing it to select all rows. But I don't know what I messed up.

How can I fix this, and are there any other problems with my attributes?

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v1.0.1.

**Edit:** If I use `.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)` or `.Where(x => x.DiplayName.Contains("mike"))` in the query, it goes a lot faster.

Generated query:

```
2016-11-01 00:14:15.9638 INFO Executed DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "x"."id", "x"."avatar", "x"."created_at", "x"."display_name", "x"."last_requested", "x"."platform_id", "x"."unique_id", "x"."updated_at"
FROM "public"."players" AS "x"
ORDER BY "x"."created_at", "x"."id"
LIMIT @__p_0
2016-11-01 00:14:16.0972 INFO Executed DbCommand (44ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "p"."player_id", "p"."season_id", "p"."playlist_id", "p"."division", "p"."matches_played", "p"."rank_points", "p"."tier"
FROM "public"."player_ranked" AS "p"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT "x"."created_at", "x"."id"
    FROM "public"."players" AS "x"
    ORDER BY "x"."created_at", "x"."id"
    LIMIT @__p_0
) AS "x0" ON "p"."player_id" = "x0"."id"
ORDER BY "x0"."created_at", "x0"."id"
Took 314ms to fetch 10 players
```

Comment: Welcome to the EF Core hell :( Although it seems to load just 10 players (the both `LIMIT` clauses)?

Comment: :) Try disabling the tracking mode and check if it help

Comment: Actually the second query looks wrong - `EXISTS` with `LIMIT`, what?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core currently is a nightmare.

You can try the following workaround (but if you ask me, better switch back to EF6).

Instead of:

```
var players = database.Players
    .Include(x => x.Ranks)
    .Take(10)
    .ToArray();
```

use:

```
var players = database.Players
    .Take(10)
    .ToArray();
var playerIds = players.Select(p => p.Id);
database.PlayerRanks.Where(r => playerIds.Contains(r.PlayerId)).Load();
```

which should produce the same effect as `Include`.

Comment: This reduced the time from ~3000ms to around ~120ms, which is pretty good. I can't go to EF6 because I have to use netstandard 1.6. Wouldn't this remove the ability to use WHERE on the ranks?

Comment: Hi @Ivan Stoev do EF core team know about these issues ?

Comment: @Sampath Hi, sure they do. Just go to their GitHub, it's full with issues :)

Comment: Hehe.. :D `482` issues up to now.+1 for your workaround.

Comment: @AeonLucid No, it wouldn't remove that ability, you can use `Where` freely, as soon as the second query (with `Load`) includes the first (master) query filter. This basically is manual explicit loading.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've editted my question with something that makes it go faster too, looks like that fixes the bad query generation?

Comment: @AeonLucid Yeah, that seem to fix it too! Long live trial and error :)